# Strange behaviour ssh -> bash --> (tty no echo) --> c program

Tags: bash, select, ssh, file-descriptor, strace

I'll try to be as clear as possible (sorry for any inconvenience)

At job we have an old C program which works with industrial hand terminals from Honeywell.

That terminal has its own ssh client to connect to a linux redhat 6.6 server. 
Once it is connected to the linux box (using a certain user), a C program is launched by the bash shell with the following parameters

```
export TERM=vt200
stty raw icrnl -echo
$APLI_EXEC/program param1 param2
```

so the flow is like => client ssh --> ssh server-> bash --> c program

The application (or it seems) is working fine but sometimes (1-3-5 times per week) a randomly terminal stops receiving data from the server but the application receives the inputs from it. It is like if you writes Ctrl+S in a shell

Debuging the application and the ssh process using strace I realized about something strange:

The app strace is fine

```
write(1, "1", 7) = 1
```

but the strace of the ssh process is not fine (I think.. and yes I saw the ioctl no echo param, but...)

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(3, "\227\316\242\350\261\330)\300e\210\352\367\2VX\24\305\2474\272\371\34\273n{\323p.\211\17H\327"..., 16384) = 48
select(14, [3 9], [11], NULL, {900, 0}) = 1 (out [11], left {899, 999996})
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(11, "1", 1)         = 1
ioctl(11, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(14, [3 9], [], NULL, {900, 0}                   <<<<
```

file descriptor used by the ssh process:

```
lr-x------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 9 -> pipe:[383586491]
lr-x------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 8 -> /var/lib/sss/mc/group
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 7 -> socket:[383586484]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 6 -> socket:[383586478]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 5 -> socket:[383586458]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 4 -> socket:[383586457]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 3 -> socket:[383585929]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 2 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 14 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 13 -> /dev/ptmx
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 11 -> /dev/ptmx
l-wx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 10 -> pipe:[383586491]
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 1 -> /dev/null
lrwx------ 1 root     root 64 Feb 15 17:12 0 -> /dev/null
```

In the select call, I miss fd #11 or fd #13 in there

Comparing this with another call

```
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(3, "\365\354\354C\10|\336-\4\342\327B0P\275&\213)\367\32\24\333)#\364\355V\3\237\337\33\204"..., 16384) = 52
select(14, [3 9 13], [11], NULL, {900, 0}) = 1 (out [11], left {899, 999997})
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(11, "a", 1)         = 1
ioctl(11, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
select(14, [3 9 13], [], NULL, {900, 0}          <<<
```

What it is going on with fd #13 in the other call?

Is it possible the C program is doing something to lock the file descriptor of ssh? I don't think so because the ssh process is owned by root and the C program is running by a normal user, but who knows

It is possible the hand terminal sends a combination of ctrl keys which they 'hangs' the standard output?

I ran out of ideas.. Can anybody drive me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Nacho.

Comment: This questions is probably more proper on the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**ServerFault**](http://serverfault.com/). If this hasn't *always* been a problem with the C program, then it is unlikely its behavior is the cause.

Comment: Hi David maybe you're right. I'll try to get lucky in these sites..Thanks for your help.